# Haskell string/output manipulation

Tags: string, haskell, output

I do have the following code:

```
suffixes :: [a] -> [[a]]
suffixes [] = [[]]
suffixes l@(_:t) = l : suffixes t

prefixes :: [a] -> [[a]]
prefixes [] = [[]]
prefixes l@x = l : prefixes (init x)

menu :: Char -> [a] -> Either String [[a]]
menu 'p' l = Right (prefixes l)
menu 's' l = Right (suffixes l)
menu x _ = Left ("(" ++ show x ++ ")" ++ "is not supported, use (p)refix or (s)uffix")
```

I do have the following test function:

```
testMenuP = "Expected Right [[1,2],[1],[]]; menu 'p' [1,2] returned " ++ show (menu 'p' [1,2] :: Either String [[Int]])

testMenuS = "Expected Right [[1,2],[2],[]]; menu 's' [1,2] returned " ++ show (menu 's' [1,2] :: Either String [[Int]])

testMenuC = "Expected Left \"(d) is not supported, use (p)refix or (s)uffix\"; menu 'd' [1,2] returned " ++ show (menu 'd' [1,2] :: Either String [[Int]])

testMenu = putStr (testMenuP ++ "\n" ++ testMenuS ++ "\n" ++ testMenuC ++ "\n")
```

My question is now, how do I get rid of the quotes '' in the Char 'd' when I output the string (as shown in the test function testMenuC).

Comment: I think your question could be replaced with: `show 'c'` returns `"'c'"`, how do I get `"c"` instaed? Or How do I convert a `Char` to a `String`. And the answer would be: use `['c']` instead of `show 'c'`.

Comment: Please remove the code that is not absolutely important. This makes it easier to spot your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the part of menu with:

```hs
menu x _ = Left ("(" ++ [x] ++ ")" ++ "is not supported, use (p)refix or (s)uffix")
```

or even

```hs
menu x _ = Left . mconcat $ ["(", [x], ")", "is not supported, use (p)refix or (s)uffix"]
```